# pythonic way of iterating over variable number of sequences

Tags: python, iteration, sequences

In some cases I think I have to use some ugly -- or at least non-pythonic -- construct to iterate of some sequence. Something like:

```
`for index in range(len(somesequence)):
    somesequence[index] + anothersequence[index]`
```

If I know the number the number of sequences (I checked the correct length in advance), then I could write much nicer code. E.g. for two:

```
for spam, morespam in somesequence, anothersequence:
    spam + morespam
```

But in the cases I use the `range(len(xXx))` construct, I don't know how many sequences there are -- so I use a nested loop and the index.

I presume that I'm still not at the plateau of the learning curve; is there a nicer way or functionality to iterate over a sequence of sequences?

Comment: Are you looking for [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip)?

Comment: Couldn't find an exact match, but the dupe target shows how to iterate on multiple sequences simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, of course it's zip. I didn't think that the iterator is automatically of the right type. So the solution is: `mastersequence = sequence_of_sequences` then one (== me) can use `for superiter in zip(mastersequence)`. Thanks!

Comment: Should I/can I delete the question?